# How to show reorder control in custom UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have implemented all needed delegate methods and set the cells `showsReorderControl` to `YES`. This would work if the `tableViewCells` were not custom.

So how do I show the ReorderControl with custom `UITableViewCells`?

Comment: There is no difference with custom cells. Is the table view in edit mode?

Comment: @rmaddy Do you mean by clicking on [navItem setRightBarButtonItem:[self editButtonItem]]; ?

Comment: That will do it assuming you are using a `UITableViewController`. Is all of the stuff you do in your custom cell being added to the cell's `contentView` and not the cell itself?

Comment: @rmaddy UITableViewController, and the cell itself. Using storyboard.

Comment: That's the problem. You must put your custom cell contents in the cell's `contentView` otherwise your stuff will cover and hide the reorder control.

Comment: @rmaddy I did what you said, but that didn't fix the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: Without seeing related code I can't think of anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41160/discussion-between-alexander-longbeach-and-rmaddy)

Comment: Heads-up everyone else: Above discussion is no good if you're using a `UIViewController`.